# Where can I find the use of Model.deleteOne in the official API documentation?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

The API documentation is found [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html), however there are two entries:

[Model.deleteOne](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.deleteOne)

and

[Model.prototype.deleteOne](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-deleteOne)

both of which do not appear to use the form I am using as I am explicitly using the form below, while the docs use it as a place holder for such things as `Character` or `product`.

```
const Model = mongoose.model(name, schema);
Model.deleteOne()
```

My delete is working fine but I want to read the actual documentation for my function.

Comment: Looks like you found it.

Comment: Its the same thing, when you dont specify anything within ```deleteOne()```, it deletes the very first document in the collection.

Answer (score 0):

If I specify nothing then nothing happens. In fact not a lot useful happens ....`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoServerError: BSON field 'delete.deletes.q' is missing but a required field.`

So we must use the param filter and provide a doc to filter and delete:

```
(method) Collection<Document>.deleteOne(filter: Filter<Document>): Promise<DeleteResult> (+3 overloads)
Delete a document from a collection

@param filter — The filter used to select the document to remove

@param options — Optional settings for the command

@param callback — An optional callback, a Promise will be returned if none
```

So like so like the defintion says `Collection<Document>.deleteOne({_id: 12345})`

OR

```
delete = (x) => { if(x) db.collection.deleteOne({_id: x});
    return 'you must provide a value to delete for field _id';
    }
```

Are you sure your method deletes one or more docs without a filter?

Comment: It works ... what language is this `Collection<Document>.deleteOne({_id: 12345})
` ... that does not look like JavaScript ...?

Comment: Maybe your method only deletes the first doc it finds then. As it says in doc if you specify no document then the first document is returned. 'Specify an empty document { } to delete the first document returned in the collection.'